# How to put marker of the locations[ ] on leaflet Map in reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, leaflet

I have been trying to put marker of the locations , of the user saved in mongodb.

```
//Get Cordinates from ALL Farms
componentDidMount(){
  const url="http://localhost:5000/api/users/viewFarm/5d3ac84a86688123789e13b2";
  fetch (url,{
      method: "GET"
  }).then(response=> response.json()).then(result=>{
      console.log(result);

     this.setState({
      farmList : result
     }); 
  });
}
```

The response from backend server for the location of the user

```
[
    [
        "11.33,22.99"
    ],
    [],
    [
        "11.22,65.33"
    ],
    [
        "32131"
    ],
    [
        "32161"
    ],
    [
        "2"
    ],
    [
        "Location"
    ]
]
```

Here i can parse the get request and get locations but
how to pass the location all the farms in the Leaflet map.

```
        <Marker position={[23.54474, 87.29164]}>
          <Popup>
            Test Popup
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
```

Comment: How does you response look like?

Comment: @kboul the response contains locations of the specific user  in an array ```[
    [
        "11.33,22.99"
    ],
    [],
    [
        "11.22,65.33"
    ],
    [
        "32131"
    ],
    [
        "32161"
    ],
    [
        "2"
    ],
    [
        "Location"
    ]
]```